# How to eliminate unused arguments in an opacity fade?

Tags: javascript

`element` is called but never used, they are just passed back to a another function call.  This seems like a waste is there a better way to do this?

**Initial Call**

```
fadeUp( document.getElementById( 'test' ), 3000 );
```

**Fades the opacity of an element up for 3000 ms**

```
function fadeUp( element, max_time )
{
    var opacity = 0;
    if( fadeUp.elapsed === undefined )
    {
        fadeUp.elapsed = 0;
    }
    fadeUp.elapsed += 10;
    opacity = fadeUp.elapsed / max_time; 
    setTimeout(function(){callBack( element, max_time, fadeUp.elapsed, opacity );},fadeUp.elapsed);
}

function callBack( element, max_time, elapsed, opacity )
{
    element.style.opacity = opacity;
    if( elapsed <= max_time )
    {
        fadeUp( element, max_time );
    }
    else
    {
        fadeUp.elapsed = undefined;
    }
}
```

**Related**

[How to create an opacity fade()? (  improvement over jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145809/how-can-i-vary-the-opacity-over-time)

Comment: FWIW I think `fadeUp.elpased` should be `fadeUp.elapsed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `element` argument is used in the callback function.  If you eliminate it from the `fadeUp()` function, then it will not be available to the callback function and your code will not work.  This is the proper way to pass `element` for use in the callback and there is not a better way to get that argument to the callback function.

If I follow what you're trying to do, then I think you can use this much simpler code that uses no static variables:

```
function fadeUp( element, max_time ) {
    var elapsed = 0;

    function next() {
        elapsed += 10;
        element.style.opacity = Math.min(elapsed / max_time, 1);
        if (elapsed <= max_time) {
            setTimeout(next, 10);
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FHq6B/.

This uses a local function and local variables with no static variables.

And, a slightly more accurate version that uses actual elapsed time to calculate the amount of fade would look like this:

```
function fadeUp( element, max_time ) {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    function next() {
        var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
        element.style.opacity = Math.min(elapsed / max_time, 1);
        if (elapsed <= max_time) {
            setTimeout(next, 10);
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

This one can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g98Tv/.

Note the additional accuracy of using actual elapsed time is probably not noticeable with a fade animation, but can be noticeable with other types of animations which is why I included it here.

Comment: @stack.user.0 - you would have to include a working example of the code (the `fade` function is not included) and describe what you're trying to accomplish here before we could propose a better way to write this.  My first intuition is that you don't need to be using static variables at all.  Local variables should work just fine.

Comment: @stack.user.0 - I added two versions to my answer that don't use any statics.

Comment: It's no big deal to call `new Date()`.  It's a very fast function.  But you can implement whichever one you want.  The second one is more likely to run the exact amount of time you set in `max_time`.  The first one is likely to run a little longer than you requested because you're not measuring time exactly, you're assuming that every timer fires exactly on time (which they don't necessarily) and that the function takes no time to execute each time (which it doesn't).

Comment: @stack.user.0 - this is much shorter than the other post because this is not nearly as generic.  This function only goes from 0 to 1 opacity.  That other function could specify a starting and ending opacity and could fade in or out.  It was more powerful (and thus required more code) to offer the additional functionality.