# .stop() & .animate() jQuery functions into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to learn the JavaScript as well. and looking the various jQuery functions to their equivalent JavaScript.

I want to convert this jQuery function to its equivalent JavaScript functions? How can I do this?

```
$('.sample').stop().animate({
    left: '-102px'
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You cannot convert this with a basic syntax change. You have to calculate all the differences and animation times. If pure javascript could do it easily, there wouldn't be a need for jquery

Comment: You should start with something other than the animation part of jQuery. That is one of the more complex parts of jQuery, that takes quite a bit of work to convert to plain Javascript.

Comment: Do you want to implement jQuery's `animate` without `jQuery`? Because a lot of thought and effort went into developing jQuery, so if you can use it I strongly suggest you use it. As thenewseattle said, jQuery _is_ a Javascript library.

Comment: *"How can I do this?"* By looking at the source code. But animations are rather complex.

Comment: That has to be one of the hardest to copy! jQuery uses promises, progress indicators etc. and the animate() method is rather complicated, you can see [it here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=_Animation), so if you have to ask, you're probably not going to be able to copy it anytime soon. There are however easy ways to create simple animations with timeouts or loops.

Comment: You can view the jQuery source code at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

Comment: I've build this code in jQuery. I'm actually looking to convert this code to Javascript. I've found equivalent JS to many of the functions but this one was left. Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G4t4f/6/. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell, a jQuery animation is a recurring timer that changes one or more CSS properties on each timer tick.

In addition jQuery implements a tweening algorithm that calculates on each timer tick, whether the animation is ahead or behind schedule and adjusts so that the animation always completes in the exact time specified.

In addition jQuery implements an animation queue so that multiple animations can be chained together (start the next one when the previous one completes).

In addition jQuery supports easing functions which allow you to specify a non-linear animation that varies it's speed during the time according to a specific algorithm.

FYI, the jQuery javascript source code is [fully available](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) if you want more details. The core of the work is in a local function called `doAnimation()`, though much of the work is done in functions called `step` and `update` which can be found with the definition of `jQuery.fx.prototype`.

Here's another answer that shows a [simple fade animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151349/how-to-eliminate-unused-arguments-in-an-opacity-fade/9151384#9151384) in pure javascript.

Here's a [general tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) on animation.

You can see a discussion of using a timer for an animation [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/).

You can see a discussion of tweening [here](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-3/).

Here's a javascript version of your specific animation:

```
// node is the DOM element to animate
// prop is the CSS property name to animate
// end is the CSS value to animate to (only supports px units)
// duration is the time of the animation in ms
// fn is an optional callback when the animation is done
//     fn is called like this fn(node, arg)
// arg is an optional argument that is passed to the callback
// context is an optional argument that is the this pointer for the function
function animate(node, prop, end, duration, fn, arg, context) {
    var stepTime = 20;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var start = parseInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue(prop), 10);
    if (typeof end === "string") {
        end = parseInt(end, 10);
    }

    function step() {
        // calc how much time has elapsed
        var nextValue, done, portionComplete;
        var timeRunning = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        if (timeRunning >= duration) {
            nextValue = end;
            done = true;
        } else {
            portionComplete = timeRunning / duration;
            nextValue = ((end - start) * portionComplete) + start;
            done = false;
        }
        // set the next value
        node.style[prop] = nextValue + "px";
        if (!done) {
            setTimeout(step, stepTime);
        } else {
            if (fn) {
                context = context || window;
                fn.call(context, node, arg);
            }
        }
    }
    // start the animation
    step();
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Mc3xD/

---

For simplicity of understanding, this doesn't implement the `.stop()` part of your jQuery example as that would need a separate data structure to keep track of each animation timer running on a given object which can be seen in a more involved version that supports `stop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mp4Yq/.

Answer (score 0):

you remind me when i started learning js , and then was very happy to find jquery , anyway i dont know why you are doing vice versa , but to answer you question

Animation in javascript can be used using setInterval function with changing the top , left .. etc attributes over a very small amount of time ( usually 24 milli secconds ) which to the human eye are like a stream and not like seperate shots of positions , also you may consider using pure css3 , however a function like this may be used

```
 var position,ratio,time,mytimer;
document.getElementById("hi").style.left=0;
function animate_left(position,time)
{
ratio=position/time;
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("hi").style.left)<=position)
{
document.getElementById("hi").style.left=(parseInt(document.getElementById("hi").style.left)+ratio*100).toString()+"px" 
}

else
{
    clearInterval(mytimer)
}
}
function animate(value1,value2)
{
mytimer=setInterval(function(){animate_left(value1,value2)},10) //where 10 is minimum smooth animation factor for human eye
}
animate(600,1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/er67f/6/