# jQuery stop() function equivalent in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have an accordion animation

```
    $(this).siblings().stop();
    $(this).siblings().find('.time').stop();
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).find('.time').stop();
```

and then the animation continues. How I can do the same in pure javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177374/stop-animate-jquery-functions-into-javascript/20177460#20177460

Comment: No, I have a working version like that example, but I need the accordion not to crash  when hovering faster

Comment: You can see the crash like this snippet https://codepen.io/uniqname/pen/gKmpz/

Comment: maybe then provide more code of your working version or redefine your question, so that we can have a deeper look into the issue

Comment: what do you mean with "crash"? For me it is working. i didn`t catch your point here.

Comment: When hovering fast the forth section is vibrating and going to top and the height of the parent div is changing, but I want heights to be changed synchronously