# Fading an image javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a series of images that toggle through on the webpage, but they just cut between each image. Is there an easy way to just fade in the next image instead of abruptly changing it?

```
var numImages = 9;

var imageArr = new Array(numImages);

for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    imageArr[i] = new Image();
    imageArr[i].src = "slideImages/image" + i + ".jpg";
}
var cnt = 1;

//change image when its clicked
document.getElementById("idSlides").onclick = function() {
    changeImage();
};

//toggle through images
function slide() {
    changeImage();
    if (cnt < numImages) {
        cnt++;
    } else {
        cnt = 1;
    }
    this.setTimeout("slide()", 2300);
}

function changeImage() {
    var img = imageArr[cnt];
    document.images.slide.src = img.src;

}
slide();
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue? How about toggling a class and handling animations in CSS? Also, this line `this.setTimeout("slide()", 2300)`... change it to `setTimeout(slide, 2300)`

Comment: Please choose one of the answers below as "accepted" (click the checkmark icon next to the answer) instead of adding "solved" to the title. If none of the answers solve your problem, you may want to add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone else will find this useful. Here's a pure CSS3/JavaScript solution that works fairly well.  Some additional work needs done to add the correct eventlisteners for IE/Safari/Moz. Works good in chrome :)

**CSS:**

```
img
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
}
.fadeIn
{
  -webkit-animation:simpleFadeIn 2s;
  animation:simpleFadeIn 2s;
  opacity:0;
}
.fadeOut
{
  -webkit-animation:simpleFadeOut 2s;
  animation:simpleFadeOut 2s;
}
.container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.hidden
{
  display:none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes simpleFadeIn
{
0%   {opacity:0;}
100%  {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes simpleFadeOut
{
0%   {opacity:1;}
100%  {opacity:0;}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"
         class='square'></img>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/101"
         class='hidden'></img>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/102"
         class='hidden'></img>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/103"
         class='hidden'></img>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/104"
         class='hidden'></img>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function()
{
var animating = false;
var currentImage;
var nextImage;

var currentIndex = 0;

var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  cycleImage();
});

function cycleImage()
{
  if(animating === false)
    {
      animating = true;
      currentImage = images[currentIndex];

      currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % images.length;

      nextImage = images[currentIndex];

  //Begin fading out
      currentImage.classList.add('fadeOut');

  //Hide div once image completes
      currentImage.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', fadeOutComplete);

  //Unhide image
      nextImage.classList.remove('hidden');
      nextImage.classList.add('fadeIn');     

      nextImage.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', fadeInComplete);
    }

}
function fadeOutComplete()
{
    this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', fadeOutComplete);
    this.classList.remove('fadeOut');
    this.classList.add('hidden');
    animating = false;
}
function fadeInComplete()
{
   this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', fadeInComplete);
   this.classList.remove('fadeIn');
}
})(window);
```

http://jsbin.com/roluzenu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Change the opacity of the image over time.

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145985/1431813) for a more in depth description of how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something along these lines:

```
function fade(img){
    var opacity = 0;
    var fade;
    fade = setInterval(function(){
        img.style.opacity = '0.'+opacity;
        opacity++;
        console.log(opacity);
        if(opacity === 9){
            img.style.opacity = 1;
            clearTimeout(fade);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Here's a working fiddle based on your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Y3U/1/

Comment: This works, but I would just like to point out its best to use CSS to control animations.  That's what shes there for. :)